# Non-immediately repeating random sequence -- terms / concepts

Tags: sequences-and-series, random

Supposing I have a fair die and record the rolls, but ignore and reroll any immediate repeats. For example, I roll:

```
3  2  1  (1)  5  6  (6)  (6)  3  1
```

And I record:

```
3  2  1       5  6            3  1
```

...and so forth, ignoring (1) and (6) (6) and in the process of generating a non-repeating sequence.

Are there special terms of art in mathematics for this kind of random non-repeating sequences, and are their concepts or equations for their properties?

For example, it seems like the number of sequences would be `6 * (6-1) * (6-1) ...` and that if next roll was not allowed to match any number of previous rolls x, then the number of possible sequences would be `n * (n-1) * (n-2) ... * (n-x) * (n-x) * (n-x) ...`

As an illustrative example, I'm thinking of the case of a music player with a large number of songs. Rather than shuffling, it randomly chooses a song, then rejects it only if it is an immediate repeat. This concept could then be extended to rejecting a song that was one of the x previous songs. This isn't a shuffle, and it isn't purely random. Are there concise ways of describing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Markov chain.  In particular, it's a random walk on the graph $K_6$.

Comment: So in the case of not repeating the previous 2 rolls, or not repeating the previous n rolls, can those also be described as Markov chains / random walks on a particular graph?

Comment: Hmm. You seem to have identified a description for the trivial example of my question only -- which does not hold for the n-back generalization or for my illustrative example, unless I am misunderstanding the "memorylessness" of Markov Chains. If the music player example could be described as a Markov chain or a random walk on a graph, could you say something about how?

Comment: The "$n$-back" generalization can also be made into a Markov chain by considering a "state" to be a sequence of $n$ rolls.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. So a 2-back for dice would be a random walk on the graph $K_{30}$ with nodes from (1,2), (1,3) ... (6,5); 3-back on $K_{150}$, et cetera? Thank you; that is very helpful.

Comment: No, not a complete graph.  For the $2$-back it's a directed graph indexed by pairs $(i,j)$, $i \ne j$, with arcs from $(i,j)$ to $(j,k)$ for $k \ne i,j$.

Comment: ...then the 4-back is a digraph indexed by quads $(i,j,k,l)$ for all quads consisting of unique elements, and with arcs from $(i,j,k,l)$ to $(j,k,l,m)$ with no elements shared ( $m \neq i,j,k,l$ )?